# Is there way to put this element on the end?

Tags: javascript, css

I need to put this element [b] at the end of the available space so it lines up at the same spot every line. But nothing works.

[image: picture 1]
[image: picture 2]

```
restOfList = albumArray.slice(3).map((d) => <Link className="artistLink" to={{ pathname: "/itemPage/" + d.id, album: d}}>{album? <div className={"artist4"}>{i++}. {d.artist} - {d.title} <b style={{color: "#720607", marginLeft: "1%", marginRight: 0, display: "inline block<i"}}>{getRating(d)}</b></div> : ""} </Link>)
```

Comment: Impossible to help with just an image. Show your code

Comment: If you share your code - and an image of code is even more useless than the image of your attempted site, and actively limits participation - we can potentially help. Please read the "*[mcve]*" guidelines, read "*[ask]*" and then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the list item with div and add a class with flex display. Then the b element will be styled with margin-left : auto